# how to define a vector with a functor

Tags: c++, stl, vector, functor

hey, i implemented the following functor:

```
struct CompareCatId : public std::binary_function<Vehicle*, Vehicle*, bool>
{
    bool operator()(Vehicle* x, Vehicle* y) const
    {   
        if(x->GetVehicleType() > y->GetVehicleType())
            return true;
        else if (x->GetVehicleType() == y->GetVehicleType() && x->GetLicenseNumber() > y->GetLicenseNumber())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

when i try to define a vector as the following i am getting alot of errors :

```
vector<Vehicle*,CompareCatId>* m_vehiclesVector;
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the error message?  And what definition of `vector` are you using?  The second argument in the template for `std::vector` is the allocator class...

Comment: What's a Vehicle? I have no problem whatsoever declaring that vector once I define a class Vehicle.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this - what do you hope to achieve by including the functor in your vector declaration?

Comment: the error message is :error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template

Comment: Vehicle is an obeject that i want to put inside my vector

Comment: i include it so i will be able to sort my vector in a way that i will be able to print the "vehicles" stuff according to my functor.

Comment: @Nadav:  The second template argument for `vector` is for the allocator.  It's trying to use your functor as an allocator, which isn't going to work.  If you want to keep the vector sorted, you need to do so yourself, either by inserting each new element into the correct position or by sorting the vector when you are done inserting elements.

Comment: I'm more concerned with why `m_vehiclesVector` is a pointer type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector` does not take a functor, so you can't.

`vector` has two template parameters:  the type of object to be stored and the allocator to be used (the allocator is optional; by default it will use `std::allocator<T>`).

The ordered associative containers (e.g., `map` and `set`) allow you to specify a comparison function because they are *ordered* containers: they have to keep their elements in some order.

If you want to keep the elements of the vector sorted you need to sort them yourself, either by inserting each new element into the correct position in the vector such that it always stays sorted or by sorting the vector after you have finished inserting elements.  Alternatively, you can use one of the ordered associative containers, like `set`.

Comment: Putting a functor in a vector shouldn't be any problems if it's assignable\copy-constructable?

Comment: @Viktor:  Yes, you can create a vector of functors assuming they meet those requirements; but that's not what the OP is trying to do.  The OP is trying to provide a functor to the vector, presumably to have the vector use it to keep the vector sorted.

Comment: @Viktor - true, but OP is trying to attach functor to vector<Vehicle>

Answer (score 0):

`vector` isn't a sorted container and as such doesn't accept a comparison type.

I think you're looking for `std::set<Vehicle*,CompareCatId>* m_vehiclesVector;`